# Can gnome-screenshot save freehand selected shots?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

Only full-screen PRTSC will save the screenshot in the Pictures folder. However, can I make gnome-screenshot save the image even if I'm only screenshotting a window or freehand selection?

Comment: this works out of the box for 18.04 install. what version of Ubuntu are you running, and what is the auto-save-directory set up for in dconf-editor?

Comment: Really? 18.04. Well, full screen snaps go to Pictures and that's fine. Where does gnome-screenshot store freehand snaps? They're not there.

Comment: `man gnome-screenshot` lists the various options. What do you mean by freehand selection? You can save a selected area by dragging with the mouse but that will be rectangular only.

Comment: Yes, and as I ask above, can I make gnome-screenshot save the selected screenshot area, just like it does if I screenshot the entire screen (the file saved in Pictures).

Comment: gnome-screenshot only has 1 auto-save-directory setting, all screenshots, full screen, active window and selected area should be saved in the same place. Do you have dconf-editor installed?

Comment: Yes, the folder is Pictures, but only full screens are saved, and not the rest. What can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: By default (new 18.04 install), the default for auto-save-directory is '' (empty string) not 'Pictures' . If the output of 'gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory' is 'Pictures' try setting it to '' (empty string). May need a reboot to take effect.

Comment: also, are we to assume you're using the keyboard shortcuts as configured in Keyboard Shortcuts (Settings > Devices > Keyboard)?

Comment: The default is Pictures, that's where I find the full screen screenshots. So where do screenshots go now, when I set to "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> to capture "freehand selections", they are not saved anywhere, they just get copied to the clipboard. You can then paste them to other applications, for example GIMP.

If you want to capture "freehand selections" and save to Pictures by default, then try any of the following.

1. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>.
2. Use the following command

   ```
   gnome-screenshot -a
   ```
3. Use the "*Screenshot*" application. It lets you capture the screenshot and provides the options to save to a specific folder or copy to clipboard.

Comment: OK, the terminal command does the trick. Shame shortcuts don't do the same. Perhaps suggestions to gnome are in order. Thanks!

Comment: Shortcuts do the same... You just need to use  (Shift+PrtSc) instead of using  (Shift+Ctrl+PrtSc).

Comment: @Ramuyko Ah, yes, that's true. I have appended to my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I was going for. Thanks @Ramuyko

Comment: @pomsky sorry to ask for a clarification. [I asked the questioner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035198/can-gnome-screenshot-save-freehand-selected-shots#comment1684309_1035198) but didn't get a response. So, in the context of `gnome-screenshot`, what is a "freehand selection" if not just a rectangle?

Comment: @DKBose I believe by "freehand selection" OP meant taking screenshot of a custom rectangular selection as opposed to the whole screen or current window, not other custom shapes instead of rectangles.